# maven aspectjrt 1.6.11 doesn't have @ajcITD annotation on aspected classes

Tags: maven, aspectj

We have recently upgraded maven-aspectj-plugin and aspectj jars from 1.2/1.6.5 to 1.4/1.6.11
Ever since, my application doesn't find the aspected methods on the classes and throws a 'MethodNotFound' exception during runtime.
One thing I have observed by decompiling the aspected classes for the different versions is that the newer version doesn't have the @ajcITD annotation anymore.

1.6.5:

```
@ajcITD(targetType="test.TestBase", name="getTestDetails", modifiers=1)
public List<TestDetail> getTestDetails() { return      
TestBaseExtentions.ajc$interMethod$
  test_TestBaseExtentions$TestBase$getTestDetails(this); }
```

1.6.11:

```
public List<TestDetail> getTestDetails() { return     
TestBaseExtentions.ajc$interMethod$
  test_TestBaseExtentions$TestBase$getTestDetails(this); }
```

Any ideas as to whether this is causing the runtime failure would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try including [aspectjtools](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.6.11/) dependency which contains this annotation definition.